# How to use angular model change and double binding simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have some trouble with the angular binding model:

I have two lists (classes and students). On the student-detail page, I want to:

1. Present all the classes available;
2. Toggle to "true" the classes that the student already takes.
3. Allow the user to add/remove classes.

I have no problem to do either 2 or 3 - but I can't do both.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let cls of listOfAllClasses">
  <ion-label>{{cls.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="cls.checked (ngModelChange)="pushClsToStudent(cls)">
  </ion-toggle>
</ion-list>
```

The Javascript:

```
pushClsToStudent(cls) {
   cls.checked? this.student.classes.push(cls) : this.student.classes.filter(c => c.classId !== cls.classId)
```

The problem is that it makes angular fire two events (1. (ngModel) 2. (ngModelChane). But I don't know how can I bypass it.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `()` from `NgModel` directive:

```
<ion-toggle [ngModel]="cls.checked" (ngModelChange)="pushClsToStudent($event, cls)">
```

This way, `ion-toggle`'s value will be binded to value of `cls.checked` and `pushClsToStudent(cls)` will be fired when you change input's value. You need to add `event` parameter to your `pushClsToStudent()`'s function in order to catch and assign new value to `cls.checked`:

```
pushClsToStudent(event: any, cls: any) {
    this.cls.checked = event;
    ...
}
```

Note:

You are missing `"` in code you posted, it would cause error for you:

```
[(ngModel)]="cls.checked    ||    [(ngModel)]="cls.checked"
```